# Instance of the product patented?

Tags: search, us20130186888

I am trying to find a good image of the design in [this patent application](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130186888?dq=US+20130186888&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KcFvUovEJc7i4AOjhoHgDg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAA), but the application itself does not contain any good depictions of the actual microwave oven.

Does anyone know of a good way to find examples of or existing products that use some patent?

Answer (score 2):

The existence of a patent does not necessitate the existence of a product.

It is very common for patents to be written prior to any product development. The inventor may simply want to protect an idea prior to seeking investment for product development, or the product development may simply stall and never make it to market.

In software patents especially, there may never be any intention for the inventor to develop the described product, but the filing of a patent may simply just be a defensive strategy to protect a larger product strategy which can be too difficult (or disallowed) to patent or copyright in its own right.

For the particular patent it sounds like a [portable microwave oven](https://www.google.com/search?q=portable%20mocrowave%20oven) for which there are plenty on the market, but whether any fits the patent description will have to be judged by an expert.